# How to configure excludes for polymer-build

Tags: polymer

When using PolymerProject via PolymerBuild to configure and build a website, I would like the ability to exclude certain Javascript files from being inlined. Previously in gulp-vulcanize this had been accomplished via adding the file path to the "excludes" config option.

However, the PolymerConfig class does not seem to support setting options for the bundler directly, and so I was wondering how they could be set.

Upon further inspection it appears that the BuildBundler class within polymer-build does not seem to pass any additional parameters to the Bundler class that is being instantiated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any solution to this?